# Changing from one button to another button when they have similar names

Tags: c#, button

I am making the game Mastermind where you need to guess a secret code with colours.

I am trying to have it when I click a button that has a colour on it, to change other buttons colour. So if you click the Red button it will change the first button on the form to Red, then if you clicked the Blue button it will change the second button on the form to Blue.

I have tried coding this before but I used only if statements, which is long and not clean at all. Especially when it comes to hundreds of statements.

```
Button btn = (Button)sender;
if (btn.Text == "Red")
{
    // I want it to automatically go to Colour2 next, 
    // instead of me having to write it a bunch of times
    Colour1.BackColor = Color.Red;        
}
```

I want to be able to smoothly go through all the different buttons on the form and change all of there colours.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Maybe create a `List<Button>` to store your buttons and just maintain the current index of the list?

Comment: If you have the user select a color first and then click where the button where they want it to go, that might be easier because you could assign the same `Click` event handler to all the buttons, which would be something like: `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { (sender as Button).BackColor = SelectedColor; }`. Perhaps if you present a little more code, or describe how you're getting a selected color from the user and the location to place it, this might be easier to answer.

Comment: Note that after a row is locked, you'd need to remove the click event handler for the buttons in that row.

Comment: @Rufus L so I have 4 buttons with different BackColors on them, such as Red, Blue, Green and Yellow. Those are the only buttons you can click, but from what you have suggested I will have one row enabled at a time and then disable it when the next row is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your existing code as an example, you could parse the text from the button into the correct enum value (assuming the `Text` value is a known color enum string) using the static `Enum.TryParse` method, which tries to parse a string to an enum. If the parsing is successful, it returns `true` and sets the `out` parameter to the parsed value:

```
Color selectedColor;

if (Enum.TryParse((sender as Button).Text, out selectedColor))
{
    Colour1.BackColor = selectedColor;
}
```

If you're certain that the `Text` property will always be a valid color (which you should be since you control it), then you could reduce that to just one line, using the static `Enum.Parse` method, which takes in the type of enum to return and a string value to parse:

```
Colour1.BackColor = Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), (sender as Button).Text);
```

Alternatively, instead of using the `Text` property, you could use the button's backcolor itself to assign the value (assuming you set it to the same color as the text):

```
Color1.BackColor = (sender as Button).BackColor;
```

Comment: Thank you, the last one worked perfectly, and its what I needed. Now I need to make a `List<Button>`